# RegEx with [[ and ]] and my sanity

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have this string that can be repeated multiple times in a variable:

`[[-1234-]]` where '1234' is the numeric variable. I just need to use preg_replace to do something like:

`[[-1234-]]`

to

`<a href=$1><img src=/images/$1></a>`

But I am blanking pretty hard.

The blocks are occurring mainly on the escape characters, which I have read are `[` and `]` and the manner in which an include replace occurs.

Comment: what did you try so far?

Answer (score 1):

`[` and `]` are metacharacters, you just need to escape them with a backslash:

```
\[\[-(\d+)-\]\]
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uF5zS3/1)

`\[\[-` means `[[-` literally, `(\d+)` will match an integer and capture it (`\d` is a digit, `+` means *one or more times*), and `-\]\]` means `-]]` literally.

Note that in the last case you could simply directly write `-]]`, but I prefer `-\]\]` because it's more self-documenting IMO.

In PHP you have to add regex separators (`#` in the following example):

```
preg_replace('#\[\[-(\d+)-\]\]#', '<a href=$1><img src=/images/$1></a>', $input)
```

No need to double-escape the backslashes if you use single quotes (except when the backslash is used to escape another backslash). This is equivalent to:

```
preg_replace("#\\[\\[-(\\d+)-\\]\\]#", '<a href=$1><img src=/images/$1></a>', $input)
```